# Удаление JS-кода из html

Tags: html, python, парсер

Необходимо удалить весь JS-код из кода страницы. Теги html уже удалил, теперь необходимо сделать это с JS кодом, чтобы в итоге у меня остался только текст. Код, который у меня есть:

```
# получаем html код страницы
request = requests.get(url)
# парсим его с помощью BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(request.content, 'lxml')

#Удаляем html-теги и выводим
textFromPage = soup.text
print(re.sub("<.*?>","", textFromPage))
```

Какие есть способы это сделать? Или может сразу можно обойти этот этап, просто вытащив текст из тегов?

Comment: Лучше это делать через сами BeautifulSoup и lxml, а не регулярки. lxml умеет и удалять теги, и удалять атрибуты, и даже просто вытаскивать текст из тегов; можно почитать про это в документации и на английском SO

Comment: Сколько я искал, я нашёл только разбор для известных конкретных тегов. А мне нужен универсальный краулер, на одном сайте текст есть внутри тегов <snap> или <a>, на других внутри <h2>. Теги разные, как мне сразу все охватить?

Comment: Не понял проблемы, для получения текста в lxml есть метод text_content, и ему глубоко наплевать какие теги используются

Answer (score 0):

Можно весь html - код преобразовать в массив и с помощью цикла найти теги script,/script,узнать их расположение в массиве. Потом с помощью срезов удалить, что требуется. (Но это не эффективно)